# Fade In and Out Audio in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, nstimer

I am wondering if there is some way to fade in and out audio using AVAudioPlayer in CocoaTouch, with a pause command once the music finishes fading and then a play command once the fading begins.  I have heard that one can use NSTimer for this purpose, but I am unsure of the easiest way to accomplish this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good video tutorial to do this here: [Playing a sound, and fading a sound using AVAudioPlayer on iPhone](http://blog.codebeach.com/2009/11/playing-sound-and-fading-sound-using.html).